# Could not connect Custom Visual server in powerBI

Tags: jquery, node.js, powerbi

I am getting this error when trying to run 'pbiviz start' command in Node.js command prompt.
[Error while running pbiviz command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYoJu.jpg)

If you have any idea what this error is all about, Please answer
Thank You

Comment: Make sure to update your `pbiviz` package. 
Try building [this simple barchart visual](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals).

Answer (score 0):

Ravi -- I was running into what appeared to be the same issue ([Error running "pbiviz start" in new project folder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44189363/8066938)) and got an answer that might help in your case.

Your first error line indicated that the folder "node_modules" and it's contents are not present in the project folder.

User "Morgan" suggested running the command "npm install" from the command line in the new project folder. So, you would first run the "pbiviz new " then change directory to the new project and run "npm install" which will create the missing structures.

In my case that allowed the build to complete.