# Error running "pbiviz start" in new project folder

Tags: powerbi

This appears to be the same issue another person posted earlier today ([Could not connect Custom Visual server in powerBI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44175988/8066938)) but I can supply additional information applicable in my own environment.

There is one answer recommending building the simple bar chart example, but I understand that the sample visual.ts that was created by the "new" command should build.

I **am** running the command from within the project folder where the pbiviz.json file was created with the "new" command.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19uPr.png) is an image showing a directory listing for the folder as well as the output for the operation. What I see is that the initial error line is looking for a folder path starting directly under the project folder with "node_modules" -- and that is not there at all.

So, am I running into a problem with the version something or do I need to install something additional, or ???

I had been following the steps from the Readme.md documentation at Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals folder on github and have had no errors until this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try type in your directory: `npm install`, and then `pbiviz start`.

Comment: The "npm install" step I hadn't seen before and added the pieces needed for build to complete. The second one shouldn't have the "npm " at the beginning though.